# Universal property of the direct product, proof verification

Tags: functions, proof-verification, universal-property

> Let $I$ be a set. For every $i\in I$ let a set $X_i$ be given, and for every $j\in I$ denote $p_j:\prod_{i\in I} X_i\to X_j$, $p_j((x_i)_{i\in I}):= x_j$, the j-th projection.
>
> If $X,Y$ are sets let $\operatorname{Hom}(X,Y):=\{\text{Function}\,\, f: X\to Y\} $. The set of all functions $f: X\to Y$.
>
> Show, that for every set $X$ is $\varphi: \operatorname{Hom}(X,\prod_{i\in I} X_i)\to \prod_{i\in I}\operatorname{Hom}(X,X_i)$, $f\mapsto (p_i\circ f)_{i\in I}$ is a bijection.

First of all the statement is clear, for $X=\emptyset$ since there is nothing to show.
For $X\neq\emptyset$ I proceed as follows:

To show, that $\varphi$ is injectiv, should be easy:

Let $f, g\in \operatorname{Hom}(X,\prod_{i\in I} X_i)$ be arbitrary and $\varphi(f)=\varphi(g)$.

I want to show, that $f=g$. Which means, that $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x\in X$.

$\varphi(f)=\varphi(g)\Leftrightarrow (p_i\circ f)_{i\in I} = (p_i\circ g)_{i\in I}$

$\Leftrightarrow p_i((f(x)))_{i\in I}=p_i((g(x)))_{i\in I}$

$\Leftrightarrow f_i(x)=g_i(x)$ for every $i\in I$.

[Where $f_i(x)$ notes the i-th coordinate of $f(x)$]

$\Leftrightarrow f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x\in X$.

$\Leftrightarrow f=g$.

Now I struggle, to show, that $\varphi$ is surjective.
I tried to make an example to understand better, what is happening:

So $X=X_1=X_2=\{1,2\}$.

Now I take an element $(g, h)\in\prod_{i=1}^2 \operatorname{Hom}(X, X_i)$, where $g(1)=1, g(2)=1$ and $h(1)=2, h(2)=2$.

> How can I choose a reasonable preimage?

I thought I just take the function $f\in \operatorname{Hom}(X, \prod_{i=1}^2 X_i)$ with $f(1)=(1,2)=(g(1), h(1))$ and $f(2)=(1,2)=(g(2), h(2))$

Then I get what I want: $\varphi(f)=(g, h)$

> For the generalization

For a give $(g_i)_{i\in I}\in\operatorname{Hom}(X,\prod_{i\in I} X_i)$ we construct the preimage $f: X\to \prod_{i\in I} X_i$ by $f(x)=(g_1(x), g_2(x),\dotso )$

> $f$ is indeed a preimage of $(g_i)_{i\in I}$

Proof:

$\varphi(f)=(p_i\circ f)_{i\in I}=(p_i(f(x))_{i\in I}=(f_i(x))_{i\in I}=(g_i(x))_{i\in I}$ for every $x\in X \Leftrightarrow \varphi(f)=g$.

So $\varphi$ is indeed a bijection.

> Further question:

Is this an instance, where one uses the axiom of choice?

I would be grateful if someone checks this and might point out mistakes I might have made.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ \{\lambda_j: X \to X_j\}_{j\in I}$ be a cone over $\{X_j\}_{j \in I}$. The UMP of the product gives us a $\textit{unique}$ arrow $\phi:X\to \prod_{j\in I} X_j$ such that $p_j\circ \phi=\lambda_j$ for each $j\in I$. This means that the map  $\Phi:\text{Cone}(X,(X_j)_{j\in I})\to \text{Hom}(X,\prod_{j\in I} X_j)$ that sends the cone $ \{\lambda_j: X \to X_j\}_{j\in I}$ to $\phi$ induces the injection $(\lambda_j)_{j\in I}=(p_j\circ \phi)_{j\in I}\mapsto \phi$.

On the other hand, given an arrow $\phi:X\to \prod_{j\in I} X_j,\ \Phi$ sends the cone $ \{p_j\circ \phi: X \to X_j\}_{j\in I}$ to $\phi$ and so the induced map is also a  surjection.

Comment: I am not familiar with category theory, if your answer is related to it. 
What is UMP.

Comment: The Universal Mapping Property of the product is part of the $\textit{definition}$ of product. Or what is your definition of product? BTW: the definition of product also uses AC by default, at least if you are working in the category Sets. That is, the product of a collection of sets $\{X_j\}_j$  is the collection of choice functions (tuples):$j \mapsto x_j\in  X_j$.

Comment: Have you checked my proof? The definition of the product is just defined as the set of all i tuples.

Comment: You can prove that the map in my answer is a bijection by brute force. Take two sets of maps $(\lambda_j)$ and $(\tau_j) $ and show that if they are dfferent, then the $\phi$'s they induce must be different, too. This proves injectivity. Whici is what you did I think. Surjectivity follows by the last line in my answer, with no changes. I did check your proof. Your proof of injectivity is fine. I just thought I would generalize the idea, because products are very important in more abstract settings. I will be happy to delete my answer if you wish.

Comment: I know, but I still prefer a proof verification, because I want to give a proof that is as basic as possible. No category theory. No UMP. :)

Comment: You do not have to delete your answer. Your answer is fine, but unfortunatly is not what I asked for. I am mainly interested in a proof verification and not simpler proofs. Others might find your answer useful. No need to delete it.

Comment: I can verify your proof. It is fine. I am happy to upvote it. And as I mentioned, the Axiom of Choice $is$ used in the construction of the product.

Comment: Thank you very much!