# Cartesian products of a family of sets, why we need to define it as a set of functions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Indeed, I partially understand defining the cartesian product as a set of functions, but I do not understand why we need to do that.

> Let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ be sets. We have defined a point $$x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in \prod_{i=1}^n X_i$$ as an ordered sequence such that $x_i\in X_i$.

Similarly can we define $\prod_{i\in I}X_i= \{(x_i)_{i \in I};x_i \in X_i \}$? Why does this set not make sense, so we must define the product as a set of functions shown below?

> **DEFINITION**  Let $\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$ be an indexed family of sets. The product  of the sets $\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$,
> written  $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ consists of all functions $f$ with domain the indexing set $I$ having the property that for each $i \in I$, $f(i)\in X_i$.

Comment: What other construction would you prefer? This construction works, it's easy to use (once you become conversant with it), and any other construction will be canonically bijectable with it. And what exactly does $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ mean, if not "a set where for each $i\in I$, we have a specific $x_i\in X_i$", i.e. a function?

Comment: I prefer to define it as in the second paragraph, as some $I$-tuple. I do not understand why we need to define it as functions if $I$-tuple is good.

Comment: Your approach requires a prior definition of an infinite tuple $(x_i)_{i\in I}$. $I$-tuples aren't given to us in nature: we need to define them, and thinking of them as functions is the best way to go.

Comment: But what *is* an "$I$-tuple"? For an arbitrary set $I$, what does $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ mean? What *set* is it?

Comment: I know what set $(a,b)$ is. Inductively I can define $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$. But what about other index sets? Finite sets without any order? Infinite sets that are not ordered, not well-ordered? What is an $\mathbb{R}$-tuple?

Comment: We have $n$-tuple, the reason why $I$-tuple does not work is because $I$ may not have order?

Comment: @Andrew_Ren it can be unordered and uncountable. There are no restriction on $I$.

Comment: *You* want to use "$I$-tuples". So it is up to you to tell us what they are for *arbitrary* index sets, and not just for sets of the form $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Again, how would you describe an $\mathbb{R}$-tuple (and $\mathbb{R}$ has an order, by the way), in a manner that does not suggest that you are assigning to each $r\in\mathbb{R}$ some element... i.e., as a function with domain $\mathbb{R}$? I think you'll find that if you try to nail down what "$I$-tuple" should mean for arbitrary sets $I$, you will discover you are just using the standard definition.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3158895/products-and-the-axiom-of-choice/3158900#3158900.

Comment: So the reason is not the order, but the cardinal number?

Comment: The reason is the **construction**. You are given an *arbitrary* set $I$. You don't have any structure to it. All you know is that it is a set. Now tell us what an $I$-tuple is. It is not about order, it is not about cardinalities.

Comment: What I mean is if $I$ is finite or countably infinite, then $I$-tuple makes sense. But as you said we know nothing about $I$.

Comment: No, even if finite, it may not "make sense". If $I=\{\text{chair},\text{horse},\text{president}\}$, what is an $I$-tuple? What is a $\mathbb{Q}$-tuple? You *think* it " makes sense", but you aren't actually defining these things except for very special kinds of finite and countable $I$. Again: *arbitrary* set.

Comment: There is a good discussion on this in Pinter, A book of set theory in the part preceding the definition of generalized cartesian product, 2.32.

Comment: Where is this definition from? The definition I an used to defines the Cartesian Product, A $\times$ B as the set of all ordered pairs (a,b) where a is in A and b is in B.